# How to convert long verbal datetime to timestamp(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, I have a bad date format, something like this -

> 'Tue Aug 06 18:22:59 EDT 2019'

I am trying to convert it to the following date format -

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

I have tried various TO_TIMESTAMP versions but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions/ help is truly appreciated.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('Wed May 29 23:36:39 EDT 2019', 'DY MON DD HH:MM:SS YYYY')
```

**Error msg -** Can't parse 'Wed May 29 23:36:39 EDT 2019' as timestamp with format'DY MON DD HH:MM:SS YYYY'

Comment: If EDT is always the case you could try: `SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('Wed May 29 23:36:39 EDT 2019', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS EDT YYYY')`

Comment: Yes it will be only EDT, and I did try the above option too, it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Snowflake does have actual datetime types. If you're seeing weird data there, you should also _fix the schema_, because if the field uses something from the varchar family of types things really are _broken_.

Comment: No, this is data I am trying to parse from a JSON source on the Snowflake platform, this is not a Snowflake data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in my Snowflake environment:

```
    SELECT to_timestamp('Wed May 29 23:36:39 EDT 2019', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS EDT YYYY') as dt
```

Using MI for minutes (not MM).

Output:   `2019-05-29 23:36:39.000`

Comment: Huh, I did overlook that detail! Thanks for pointing that out! It works

Comment: What happens when it's not Eastern Daylight Time? The `EDT` doesn't account for other timezones or standard v daylight time.

Comment: @GregPavlik Per his comments, he said it will always display EDT. He can adjust if that changes later.

Comment: Thanks, @Isolated I missed that in the comments. I may open a different question dealing with timezone abbreviations rather than offsets. If it hasn't already been asked and answered on the Snowflake tag, I'm sure it will come up.